# Can I express $\vec{v}$ in $\vec{v} \cdot \vec{x} = c$ as $\vec{v}= c \vec{x}/ \left| \vec{x} \right|^{2}$?

Tags: vectors

Suppose I have a formula like this

$ \vec{v} \cdot \vec{x} = c $

where $\vec{v}$ and $\vec{x}$ are non-zero vectors (dimension greater than $1$) and $c$ is a non-zero scalar.
Can I express $\vec{v}$ as

$\vec{v} = c \vec{x} / \left| \vec{x} \right|^{2}$

If I cannot, is there any method to express $\vec{v}$ in term of $\vec{x}$ ? Thank you very much for your help and I am waiting for your reply.

Comment: This is unreadable.  If all you know is that $\vec v\cdot \vec x = c$ then you can't determine $\vec v$.  Is that what you are asking?

Comment: To see that $\vec v$ is not determined by $c, \vec x$ just try examples.  For instance $\vec {v_1}=(1,0),\vec {v_2}=(2,0)$, $\vec x = (0,1)$ and $c=0$.

Comment: I am asking is there any way to express vector v in a unique way like inverse of matrices.

Comment: Well, since $\vec v$ is not determined by the formula, the answer is "certainly not".

Comment: What do you mean by "not determined by ⃗ ⋅⃗ = "?

Comment: I gave you an example of two distinct vectors $\vec {v_1},\vec {v_2}$  and a specific $\vec x$ and $c$ such that both of the $\vec {v_i}\cdot \vec x =c$.

Answer (score 0):

If $\vec x$ is a fixed (nonzero) vector, the set of vectors $\vec v$ satisfying your equation is a line (in the plane) or plane (in 3-space) with normal vector $\vec x$ passing through the point $c\vec x/\|\vec x\|^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\vec y$ be any vector that is perpendicular to $\vec x$.  That is, $\vec x\cdot\vec y=0$.

Then, the vector $\vec z=\frac{c\vec x}{|\vec x|^2}+\vec y$ satisfies the expression $\vec z\cdot \vec x=c$.

Hence, given $\vec v\cdot\vec x=c$, we cannot deduce that $\vec v=\frac{c\vec x}{|\vec x|^2}$.

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can. And feel free to up vote and accept an answer as you see fit.